# Connection refused error in Android

Tags: android

I was running my application fine.There were some changes in the network,like my router and internet connection got changed.Suddenly in the LogCat,I see an error like connection refused.I have provided the static IP still I get the same error.

I am running my server on my laptop and the app on the device. Intially I was able to access the application through the app and also through the browser.Can you guide me and does my Android device needs a new setting that I am missing?

Comment: You can try resetting your ADB from DDMS, it will reset ADB connection.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you faced some networking problem. So, the diagnostic is the same as for any connected device.

1. check local Android firewall - try to connect to some another server, like facebook.com or google.com
2. check your laptop firewall settings
3. draw your network schematic carefully and think what should be working and how
4. try tcpdump\wireshark to see what's actually going on the wire

Hope you win!

Answer (score 0):

Well the static IP works not sure why it was not working before may be because I was using a LAN connection only for laptop not a same WIFI connection both for laptop and android device.